# String variable as operator

Tags: string, variables, lua, conditional-statements, operators

I'd like to know if I can store operator (`==`,`~=`,`>` and so) in a string variable ad use like this

```
local a, b, op = 1, 2, ">"
if b op a then print("print something") end
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a variable as arithmetic operator in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65746996/using-a-variable-as-arithmetic-operator-in-lua). TL;DR; use a table to map the string containing the operator to the operation itself.

Comment: You can define function `eval(arg1, op, arg2)` and use it `if eval(b, op, a) then`